# When should you buy and plant hop rhizomes?

Tags: hops, grow, rhizome

I want to grow a couple of hop bines this year.  Most of the online brew supply places say they ship in late March / early April.  I have a feeling I'll still have snow on the ground around that time.  Here in Western PA we typically plant our gardens in early May.  Last year it was mid-late may before the last frost hit and I could get my veggies in the ground.

If I order hop rhizomes and they arrive in early April, how should I store them?  Should I get them in the ground as soon as they arrive, like transplanting a dormant shrub?  Or should I store them in paper bags in the basement like tulip bulbs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most places seem to do it like a pre-order deal.  Whether they'll have any extra stock if you don't pre-order is probably a crapshoot.

They usually come in a plastic bag.  Keep them moist and cold if you can't plant right away.

Several of the hops suppliers have notes on growing your own as well.  Check out Fresh Hops advice here: http://www.freshops.com/hop-growing/hop-gardening/#planting